# How to trigger hover when dragging ghost element over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm using HTML5 drag and drop. How do I get the hover event to trigger when the ghost element is being dragged over the div? The below code works if I just move the mouse over, but not when I'm dragging an element over.

```
$(".droppable").on("mouseover", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('droppable-border');
}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass('droppable-border');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just use the ondragover and ondragleave event attributes

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #droptarget {
            float: left; 
            width: 200px; 
            height: 35px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
          }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me into the rectangle</p>

   <div id="droptarget" ondragover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'green'" ondragleave="this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### **OR You can use jquery**

```js
$('#droptarget').on('dragover',function(){
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
});

$('#droptarget').on('dragleave',function(){
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #droptarget {
                float: left; 
                width: 200px; 
                height: 35px;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
              }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me into the rectangle</p>

       <div id="droptarget"></div>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```